# Collective nouns - singular vs. plural verbs?

Tags: grammatical-number

What about "youth"?
As in: 
"The youth of today is highly interconnected in many ways." 
vs.
"The youth of today are highly interconnected in many ways."

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/youth) has: **youth** noun (YOUNG PEOPLE)
B1 [U, + sing/pl verb] ​young ​people, both ​male and ​female, ​considered as a ​group. >>  It licenses either a singular or a plural verb. But the choice isn't totally free. And I think 'youth' is a tricky case. You'd use 'are' if you're considering individual members, but 'is' if you're considering the group as a whole, almost a ...

Comment: gestalt. I'd probably choose 'are' here (The young folk of today are highly interconnected ...), but can imagine some cases where it could be a lot trickier to decide (The youth of today is/are given too much freedom).

Answer (score 1):

Some nouns refer to multiple things but are still treated as one entity (for example, a pair of scissors).

Although "the youth of today" refers to multiple people, youth is still a singular noun naming a single entity, so you'd use "is".

Note that you could, if you wanted, also say

> The youths of today are highly interconnected in many ways.

but this would be awkward by virtue of "the youth of today" being a commonly-used and popular phrase.

Comment: CDO says that 'youth' may be followed by either a singular or plural verb-form.